# How can I give a foreach through the data-index JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to give a for or foreach based on my data-index to add value to each of the adesaoTest fields

If the data-index is equal to zero it normally goes through the process

The first time the code is compiled normally, but the second time when the data-index is = 1 it does not calculate

**JavaScript**

```
adesao = 0.00;

const totalAdesao = document.querySelectorAll('.quota-row');
totalAdesao.forEach(adesaoTest => {

    var index = adesaoTest.getAttribute('data-index');
    var entrada = document.getElementById(`quota-entrada-${index}`);
    var parcelas = document.getElementById(`quota-parcelas-${index}`);
    var adesaoTest = document.getElementById(`quota-adesao-${index}`);
    
    adesao = parseFloat(entrada.value) / parcelas.value;
    adesaoTest.value = adesao;
        
})
```

For each of the fields `var adesaoTest = document.getElementById(quota-adesao-${index})`
must perform calculation above

Note:
I'm using fetch to add the new entries that will go through for or foreach

When the second element is created it gives the following error

[image]

**This is the function that adds the other elements**

```
var quotasDiv = document.getElementById('quotas');

const id = quotasDiv.querySelectorAll('.row').length + 1;
var quotaPrincipal = document.getElementById('quota-principal');

const request = new Request('/configuracoes/listFormaPagamento/json', { method: 'POST' });
fetch(request)
    .then(res => {
        res.json()
            .then(data => {

                var html = `<div class="row quota-row" data-index="${id}">

            <div class="col-8" id="quota-${id}" >

                <div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <span>Entrada ${(id + 1)}</span>
                        <input onblur="calculaRestante(this)" type="text" data-index="${id}" id="quota-entrada-${id}" required="" name="entrada[]" placeholder="Primeira Parte" id="valor8" value="0"> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-2 dateInput">
                        <span>Forma de Pagamento</span>
                        <select onchange="onChangeFormaPagamento(this)" data-index="${id}" id="quota-forma-pagamento-${id}" name="forma_pagamento[]">

                            <option value="">Selecione a forma de pagamento</option> 
                            
                            ${data.map(forma_pagamento => {
                    return `<option value="${forma_pagamento.id_formas_pagamento}"> ${forma_pagamento.forma_pagamento} </option>`
                })}

                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-1 dateInput">
                        <span>Parcelas</span>
                        <select data-index="${id}" id="quota-parcelas-${id}"  onchange="calculaAdesao()" name="parcelas[]" >
                                <option value=""></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <span>Vencimento</span>
                        
                        <input data-index="${id}" type="date" required="" id="quota-vencimento-${id}" name="vencimento[]" placeholder="Entrada">
                        
                    </div>   
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <span>Adesão</span>
                        <input data-index="${id}" type="text" required="" id="quota-adesao-${id} "name="adesao[]" placeholder="Valor de entrada" id="valor6">
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <span style="color: red; cursor: pointer; margin-top: 3rem" onclick="deleteQuotaHtml(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
                    <div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>`;

                quotasDiv.innerHTML += html;


            })
    })
```

}

Comment: So if you are creating the elements based on the results of a fetch, if this logic runs before they are created, they will not exist to be found and manipulated.

Comment: Yes, but the elements are created, but when you enter the last line of code, main.js: 279 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
    at main.js: 279
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at calculaAdesao (main.js: 271)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange (registerOrder Budget: 1)

Comment: So you have a `data-index` on something that does not match a `quota=adesao-#`

Comment: You are right, this is happening precisely for this reason, I am adding the elements through fetch, you know how to tell me how I can solve this problem

Comment: It would logically make sense to perform the logic at the time that they are created.  Otherwise you can not guarantee when they are created to know to execute this logic.

Comment: The elements are not added together, I added my fetch logic for analysis. They run at different times and on different buttons